# Changes not reflected in Database while using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am accessing my database through ADO.NET Entity framework in MVC 3 Application.

I am updating my database through Stored Procedure.

But the changes are not reflected at run time.I mean to say i am able to see the changes only after  restarting it.

What is the reason for the problem and How can i avoid it ?
I am using Repository pattern So at repository My code look like this

Ther Is One Function Which Save Changes

public void SaveNewAnswer(AnswerViewModel answer,string user)
 {

```
        SurveyAdminDBEntities _entities = new SurveyAdminDBEntities();
        _entities.usp_SaveNewAnswer(answer.QuestionId, answer.AnswerName, answer.AnswerText, answer.AnswerOrder, answer.Status, user);
        _entities.SaveChanges();
```

}

Data Retreival Code

public IEnumerableGetMultipleChoiceQuestions(string questionId)
 {

```
        SurveyAdminDBEntities _entities = new SurveyAdminDBEntities();
        _entities.AcceptAllChanges();
        _entities.SaveChanges();
        return _entities.usp_GetMultipleChoiceQuestions(Int32.Parse(questionId));
    }
```

But Changes are not reflected till the time i don't clode the session of the browser and run it again .

Please help !

Thank You In advance

Comment: See what changes specifically?

Comment: Can you show us **some code** that you use for your operations? Maybe you're missing something..... (but we can't mind-read your screen....)

Comment: Can you post your SQL code for the sproc that is mapped to `_entities.usp_SaveNewAnswer()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling `context.SaveChanges()` on your Entities (DbContext/ObjectContext) object? Are you using a transaction that you haven't committed?

If you have an uncommitted transaction in your sproc, you can try creating your own entity transaction and seeing if committing your transaction will commit the nested transaction as well. The problem is that calling `SaveChanges()` automatically begins and commits a transaction, so this may not be any different than that.

I would also call `_entities.AcceptAllChanges()` in your save operation.

```
public void SaveNewAnswer(AnswerViewModel answer,string user) 
{
    SurveyAdminDBEntities _entities = new SurveyAdminDBEntities();
    _entities.Connection.Open();
    System.Data.Common.DbTransaction tran = _entities.Connection.BeginTransaction();        

    try
    {
        _entities.usp_SaveNewAnswer(answer.QuestionId, answer.AnswerName, answer.AnswerText, answer.AnswerOrder, answer.Status, user);
        _entities.SaveChanges(); // automatically uses the open transaction instead of a new one
        tran.Commit();
    }
    catch
    {
        tran.Rollback();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (_entities.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                _entities.Connection.Close();

        _entities.AcceptAllChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to call context.SaveChanges() also But change are not reflected back.There are few procedures which don't commit themselves.

Comment: @Surender - If the transaction solves your issue, `SaveChanges()` begins and commits its own transaction, so you could try just adding `AcceptAllChanges()` instead of the manual transaction to test if it works.  `_entities.usp_SaveNewAnswer(answer.QuestionId, answer.AnswerName, answer.AnswerText, answer.AnswerOrder, answer.Status, user);`  `_entities.SaveChanges();`  `_entities.AcceptAllChanges();`

Answer (score 0):

Is your stored procedure doing an explicit commit?   Things run in a database session will be available for that session, but not available to any other session until the action is committed.

Comment: I am updating via function imports. Some sp's are commiting the transaction.Some are not Commiting It.
Is there any way That i can Commit my database from entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

When you pull data out of your database into your context that data is kept in memory, separate from the actual database itself.

You will see the changes if you create a new context object instance and load the data from the database with it.

It's good practice to not use the same instance of your context object but create them on an as needed basis for individual transactions with the database.  In your case if you're updating via function imports instead of the context.SaveChanges() method then you need to refresh your context with the updated data after you commit those changes.

Comment: I am updating via function imports only.
How can i refresh the context with the updated data.

Comment: Edited my question !Please help !

Comment: @Surender - After you call the save function, the retrieve function will return an object populated with the updated data.  I would make sure that your stack is calling the functions in the right order.  If you're using Ajax, be sure that you're not seeing a cached response.  Also, be sure that the retrieve function is not being called until after the save function has successfully completed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your connect string (assuming sql 2005)

transaction binding=Explicit Unbind;

if the data is no longer available after session reset, then the problem is indeed with a transaction, if the data is then available after reset, then your problem is something different and we'll likely need more details.